# Sort a list by comparing index in Dart

Tags: dart

I want arrange this list by `list[i][1]`.

```
List lst =
[
  ['a',2], 
  ['b',5],
  ['c',3],
  ['d',1],
];
```

So it will be changed like this.

```
[
  ['d',1], 
  ['a',2],
  ['c',3],
  ['b',5],
];
```

How can i do this?
Is it possible to  make it by combining with for loop and sort()?

Comment: imaging having to update the ordered list when 1 person randomly leaves the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `sort` function:

```
lst.sort((a, b) => a[1].compareTo(b[1]));
```

Now `lst` is sorted.